# Der Husten oder Das Husten?

Tags: gender

Gewöhnlich würden die Infinitive Neutrum sein. Und andere Wörter mit der -en Endung (die schon nicht Infinitive sind; z.B. der Knochen, der Besen, der Hafen) sind maskulin.
Aber Husten ist schon ein Infinitiv, aber im Duden und Oxford Wörterbuch ist es ein Maskulin! Ist es eine Ausnahme?
[image]

**Trotzdem ist es im Langenscheidt ein Neutrum!**

[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Beide sind korrekt. Es handelt sich aber um zwei unterschiedliche Wörter.

**Der Husten:**

Bezeichnet das Krankheitsbild / das Symptom "Husten".

> Ich habe (den) Husten seit 3 Wochen

**Das Husten:**

Bezeichnet die tatsächliche "Tätigkeit", also das substantivierte Verb "husten"

> Das ständige Husten geht mir auf die Nerven

Ich hoffe, das macht den Unterschied klar.

Answer (score 9):

Beides:

*Der Husten* ist ein Substantiv und eine Krankheit.

*Das Husten* ist ein substantiiertes Verb und eine Tätigkeit ("jemand hustet")

vgl. *der Schnupfen* (die Krankheit) / *das Schnupfen* (von Tabak, z.B.)

Comment: Husten ist keine Krankheit, sondern ein Symptom.

Comment: @RHa ...dann sag' das mal dem Duden: *[Erkältungs]krankheit, bei der man oft und stark husten muss*

Comment: Von Wörterbüchern kann man nicht viel Präzision erwarten. Eher schon von Wikipedia: *Husten ist ein Symptom und meist keine eigenständige Krankheit.*

Comment: @tofro: Dem Duden müsste man vieles sagen.